# Using Javascript to modify elements for navigation

Tags: javascript

JS beginner here;

Ok, I'm trying to manipulate the functions of Codaslider for a layout. What I need is the ability to use an image for slide dynamic slide navigation.

I've solved the issue for dynamic hashing, however I'm stuck at modifying the HTML. I've tried a few things but I figure this is the easiest way...

This is what I've got so far;

```
function navigate ()
{
    var url = document.getElementById('back');
    url.href = page_back();
    return url;
}

function page_back(inward)
{
    new Object(inward.location.hash);
    var rehash = inward.location.hash.match(/[^#]/);
    if (rehash == 1) {
        rehash = 5;
    }
        else if(rehash == 2) {
            rehash = 1;
        }
            else if(rehash == 3) {
                rehash = 2;
            }
                else if(rehash == 4) {
                    rehash = 3;
                }
                    else if(rehash == 5) {
                        rehash = 4;
                    }
                        else if(rehash == null) {
                            rehash = 5;
                        }
                            else{rehash = "Invalid URL or REFERRER"}
    inward.location.hash = rehash;
    return inward.location.href;
};
```

Implemented here;

```
<a href="#5" id="back" class="cross-link"> <input type="image" class="left_arrow" src=
        "images/leftarrow.png"  onclick="navigate()" /></a>
```

What I expect this to do is change the href value to "#1" so that Codaslider will do it's thing while I provide a stationary dynamic image for slide browsing.

Anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong? page_back works fine but navigate seems to be useless.

Comment: what is Codaslider? a library? can you create a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this, it will make more sense. Also for the multiple if else, this the perfect place to use a switch statement

Comment: i intend to use a switch eventually however i had an issue with what i wrote originally so i replaced it with the working if...else. Coda slider is http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/ however it's irrelevant to the question about href modding.

Answer (score 0):

sup Josh

so to start this line here

```
new Object(inward.location.hash);
```

Unless i completely missed some javascript weirdness that line should not do any thing

the function

```
function page_back(inward)
```

takes a inward argument but you call it from navigate without an argument

```
url.href = page_back();
```

ps. the location object can be found on window.location

happy coding :D

Comment: hmm, i removed the worthless line (i thought it would prevent globalization) and i added the passed variable to the call and nothing changed :-/